# Can Wonder Woman fly in DCEU?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-84

I've read [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/74247/51336) here, and it was while ago and answer by KutuluMike was only focused on first WW movie and BvS.

With the second installment, WW84, She seems to be on air for a while, but uses her Lasso as a aid. In comics and DCAU, she have the ability of actual flight. But so far in DCEU, I've only noticed she either leaps, jumps or falling or in a aircraft whenever she is in the air.

So, in DCEU, Does she have the ability of actual flying? (like Superman, Martian Manhunter etc.. )? Or she still doesn't know she can fly(Like KutuluMike said in the linked question)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Kinda but no.

Actually, it's more like **controlled falling** than the actual *defying gravity* inherent in, say, Superman's flight.

[Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-1984-diana-flying-powers-lasso-explained/) explains:

> Diana confessed that flying was the one thing she equated most with Steve, who was a World War I pilot and spy, and it was his gift that she most envied. "I'll never understand it," Diana confessed. Steve's explanation was rather Zen: "It's so easy, really. *It's wind and air and knowing how to ride it, how to catch it. How to join with it*."

> But Diana finally understood what Steve meant after she renounced her wish and gave him up so she could regain her superpowers that the Dreamstone had stripped from her. In her anguish over losing Steve again, Diana ran at superspeed and then lashed out with her Lasso of Truth, vaulting into the air. She then used the lasso to catch a passing airliner, which launched her thousands of feet into the sky. It was there that Steve's Zen mantra about flight echoed in her ears and she finally understood she has the power to "catch air and ride the wind".

> As Diana grew more confident soaring through the skies, she also realized her magic lasso could also catch the air, the clouds, and even lightning, in order to give her acceleration.

Comment: It's sad that one of the basic qualities of WW in comics and animated, doesn't exist in DCEU. One less thing to worry about, they may thought..